# How to Get and Manipulate Elements Inside an iframe from a Relative Path in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, iframe

So I have two components (**Preview component** and an **app component**) in an angular project. I displayed one of the components (**preview Component**) inside the other(**app component**) through a relative path in an iframe:

**app.component.html**

```
 <iframe 
               src="/pagepreview"
               width="478"
               height="926"
               id="iframeId"
               #previewFrame
               >Alternative text
 </iframe>
```

Now, In the **app.component.ts** file, I want to access the elements of the preview template, so I did this:

```
 @ViewChild(`previewFrame`,{ static: true }) previewFrame: ElementRef;

  onLoad()  {
  let frameEl: HTMLIFrameElement = this.previewFrame.nativeElement;
  let showTemplate = frameEl.innerHTML
     console.log(showTemplate )

}
```

The result I got was the **Alternative text** word inside the iframe tag.

Does anyone have an idea how I can get to access the HTML tags in the preview component page? I need to do this so I can do some DOM manipulation of the **page preview component** on the **app component page**. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the page renders faster than the function that calls the DOM object, despite calling it inside an **ngAfterViewInit** life cycle hook. I added a setTimeout() function and now I'm able to get the DOM elements I want.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060078/why-is-getelementsbytagname-returning-an-html-collection-but-getelementsbytag) provided the context to my solution.